# List to single dimension of multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Is it possible **without looping** (i.e. without using for or foreach and with some LINQ or Array method) to insert the elements of a list into a single dimension of a declared multidimensional array?

For example - from list:

```
List<int> l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

To multidimensional array:

```
int [,] a = new int[5, 3]; //5 rows 3 columns
```

Such that the integers 1 to 5 populate column 3, i.e.

```
a[0, 2] = 1;
a[1, 2] = 2;
a[2, 2] = 3;
a[3, 2] = 4;
a[4, 2] = 5;
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: If there is some LINQ or Array method, it's going to be looping inside. Does that count as 'without looping' ?

Comment: No it doesn't - I just feel it should be possible to do this without for or foreach - I'll amend the question.

Comment: All of LINQ is based upon IEnumerable<T> -- it's all about looping (albeit, deferred loops with yield return).  If you can't use loops/IEnumerable, you can't use LINQ.

Comment: @Barry How exactly do you propose doing something like this without some type of looping structure? The best you can do is hide the loop with an abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List<T> has a ForEach method that you can use -- it's not LINQ, but it will get you what you want:

```
List l = new List { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
int [,] a = new int[5, 3]; //5 rows 3 columns 

int i = 0;
l.ForEach(item => a[i++, 2] = item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the standard Linq operators (at least not easily), but you can create a dedicated extension method:

```
public TSource[,] ToBidimensionalArrayColumn<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int numberOfColumns, int targetColumn)
{
    TSource[] values = source.ToArray();
    TSource[,] result = new TSource[values.Length, numberOfColumns];
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i, targetColumn] = values[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

BTW, there is no way to do it without a loop. Even Linq operators use loops internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird requirement, I'd be curious what your trying to accomplish with it.

(LinqPad example)

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    ToFunkyArray<int>(l, 4,3).Dump();
}

public T[,] ToFunkyArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int width, int targetColumn)
{
    var array = new T[items.Count(),width];
    int count=0;
    items.ToList().ForEach(i=>{array[count,targetColumn]=i;count++;});
    return array;
}
```